# CMake referencing random shell script i created in ~/bin (even after i deleted it)?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, cmake

In Ubuntu (20.04, Cinnamon desktop), I created a basic shell script to run .desktop files from the command line with these contents:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
$(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
```

and then ran `chmod +x` in order to be able to execute that as a command. Now, whenever I use `cmake --build`, it includes the contents of this file -- even after I've deleted the offending script, *and* a full restart.
Here's the output from my latest attempt to cmake:

````sh
alexander@alexander-Inspiron-7559:~/Documents/Code/CPP/SDLProject/bin$ cmake --build .
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/SDLProject/bin/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/bin where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SDLProject.dir/src/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/App.hpp:10,
                 from /home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/main.cpp:1:
/home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/text/Label.hpp:8:8: warning: character constant too long for its type
    8 | $(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
      |        ^~~~~~~
/home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/text/Label.hpp:8:35: warning: character constant too long for its type
    8 | $(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/text/Label.hpp:8:54: warning: character constant too long for its type
    8 | $(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~
/home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/text/Label.hpp:8:69: warning: character constant too long for its type
    8 | $(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
      |                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~
/home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/text/Label.hpp:8:85: warning: character constant too long for its type
    8 | $(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
      |                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/text/Label.hpp:8:2: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
    8 | $(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
      |  ^
In file included from /home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/main.cpp:1:
/home/alexander/Documents/Code/CPP/OGRE-Project-1/src/App.hpp:24:2: error: ‘Label’ does not name a type
   24 |  Label *lb;
      |  ^~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SDLProject.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/SDLProject.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/SDLProject.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2```
````

Answer (score 0):

See if the script that you created then deleted is referenced in the CMakeCache.txt file. If it is, then remove/delete the reference.

Cmake as I recall is an 'out of source directory' build tool (you create a new, empty build directory then reference your source directory). When it starts a build it generates a cache/list for files--see 'CMakeCache.txt'--to assist with dependencies at compilation time.

Deleting the 'CMakeCache.txt' file may also work for you, as it will be regenerated by cmake.

Comment: That would be a great comment, but it is not an answer per say.